# A stupid guy has thrown/threw trash here! - do they use the past tense or the present perfect tense when they don't know when the thing happened?

Tags: tense, usage

**Example 1**

> A: A stupid guy **threw** trash here!

> B: When did it happen?

**Example 2**

> A: A stupid guy **has thrown** trash here!

> B: When did it happen?

When the speaker does not know when an event happened, do they use the past tense or the present perfect tense?

Comment: We have been over this over and over and over. It depends on what you want to say. Knowing when an event happened or didn't happen does not determine the usage. The present perfect merely signals the past at the time of speaking. The simple past implies a particular moment or time he did it. So which do you want to say? Both are fine.

Comment: You know it happened in the past because the trash is there now, and it didn't travel from the future. I'm not sure what more information you need. How would the time affect the tense you use?

Comment: The present perfect refers to an event _which has present consequences_. The trash still here means there are present consequences, so the perfect is a possibility. But the simple past is also possible, if the speaker is not interested in the present state but only in the action in the past.